# Create Second SSH Account for Synology

Tags: ssh, synology

Is it possible to create a second ssh account in my synology nas that only has access to a certain directory?

I don't want the second account to have full root privileges

Comment: check the instructions here for creating an SSH user and a home for them. Then just don't give them rights to anywhere but their home. http://techanic.net/2014/04/12/configuring_ssh_and_scp_sftp_on_dsm_5.0_for_synology_diskstations.html

Comment: I was able to add the user but I am not seeing how to limit them to _only_ be able to access /volume1/USERNAME

Comment: you don't. you just make sure the user isn't part of a group that has permissions anywhere else. an absence of an allow permission is in itself a denial. The only stronger alternative is a chroot in which case you MAY want to look into this: https://sites.google.com/a/courville.org/courville/home/synology-debian-chroot

Comment: How do I even assign user groups for SSH?

Comment: say what? I think you are misunderstanding me. once you were able to login via SSH, your solution stopped having anything to do with SSH (that part is solved). its all file permissions and user groups from here out. specifically make sure that the SSH user does not have permissions to access anything except their home.

Comment: I meant to ask how do I change the permissions so a specific SSH user cannot browser other directories aside from /volume1/USERNAME